# Are there any good podcast clients for Ubuntu and alternatives?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, podcast

I was really curious to know the answer to this one.

I tried a little bit of search on the forum but there was not a question like this (although I may be wrong, and if I am, please direct me to the correct one)

So, if you have any good podcast clients that you know, please tell me.

Even if you know some blog post or video, it would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vocal from elementary OS is dedicated to podcasts (http://itsfoss.com/podcast-app-vocal-linux/).

[image: Vocal screenshot]

### Installation instructions

- stable (Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04):

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nathandyer/vocal-stable
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install vocal
  ```
- unstable daily builds (Ubuntu 14.04 and later):

  like above but with the PPA `ppa:nathandyer/vocal-daily`.

Comment: Or try "Clementine"

Comment: When I execute `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nathandyer/vocal-stable`, I get the following result: `Cannot add PPA: 'No JSON object could be decoded'.`

Answer (score 4):

You can try VLC if you want a good Podcast Audio/Video player.

VLC has a podcast parser plugin.

VLC can play podcast videos without having to download them before (like gPodder).

Go into playlist mode by pressing Ctrl+L, there you will see the following screen

[image: VLC Podcast plugin]

Click on the plus sign to add your podcast URL.

[Akregator for KDE](https://userbase.kde.org/Akregator) is a good choice as well for it is dedicated to Feeds and can also play videos (without having to download them).

Comment: You could be a bit more elaborate on that, maybe add a how to (not a link), and screen-shot etc.

Comment: @Videonauth You are absolutely right. I just added a little how-to and a screen-shot.

Answer (score 3):

Adding [Rhythmbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmbox) to the list with its ability to automatically download the latest available episodes for listening offline.

[image]

Comment: Rhythmbox works great! Ubuntu come with it already installed, so no need for a separate program just for podcasts.

Answer (score 2):

I use [gPodder](http://gpodder.org), seems to work pretty well on Ubuntu and with iPod.

Comment: Can I transfer episodes to and from my ipod (I have an ipod touch 5g)

Comment: I have the classic so not sure. You "sync" so quite possibly. Best just to give it a go, you can always uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

Have to add the music player Clementine to this list. It plays music and podcasts and even syncs with an gpodder nt so you can continus where you left off on another podcast client with gpodder support

Answer (score 0):

## [Vocal](http://vocalproject.net/)

### Pros

- Can play both audio and video Podcasts
- Automaticly warn / download new episodes
- Automaticly remove old podcasts to reserve space
- Very pretty and simple disign

### Cons

- Lack of support for iTunes podcast store

## [Gpodder](http://gpodder.org/)

### Pros

- Gpodder can create podcast playlists and sync them to media devices
- It has a time-streaching option ot make playback slower or faster
- Support for YoutTube, Souncloud and Vimeo feeds.

### Cons

- No player itself you have to open audio and video podcasts in an external program

Comment: It would be better to include the essential parts of the article with a link to it rather than just the link.